# Android show actionbar moves content in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigationview

So:

1. Activity has NavigationView with action bar.
2. There are 2 fragments - #1 and #2.
3. In fragment #2 I need to hide action bar.

Ok, successfully did it with

```
getSupportActionBar.hide()
```

But when I return to previous fragment and call

```
getSupportActionBar.show()
```

**content of fragment #1 is moved down on the height of my actionbar**.

I've tried to call .show() method onPause() of fragment #2, onResume() of fragment #1, onCreateView() of fragment #1 (before inflating a view) - no result, half of my floatingActionButton is moved below the screen.

OnCreateView() is called in fragment #1 after dismissing fragment #2, but it seems that view is not redrawing. Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: Ok, some temporary solution is to call fab.requestLayout() in postDelayed (in 1 ms). But this is so ugly, imo.

Comment: Sure, one more option is to handle pressing back button and create every time a new instance of fragment instead of popping them from backstack. But I also don't like this too much.